# how iOS play the video by URL

Tags: url, video

I want to play a video by the URL. I see some sample,the codes like below:

```
NSString *movieFile= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"android" ofType:@"mp4"];
videoURL=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:movieFile];
moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
```

It play only the local resource.I write some code like:

```
NSString* strurl =@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/adplayer/colgate.mp4";
videoURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strurl];
moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
```

but there is nothing ... why..and how to play video by the url ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: strurl];
```

Answer (score 17):

In following code, I am playing a video over the internet from a movie file located on a web server. Dont forget to add MediaPlayer framework and include "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h" in ViewController.h file.

On a button click use following code:

```
    -(IBAction) playVideo:(id)sender
     {

            NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];

            MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

            moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
            moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
            [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
            [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
     }
```

Notification method:

```
    - (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
      {

               MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];

               [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

               if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
               {
                        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
               }
      }
```

Comment: Need to add MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer globally otherwise it will not work .

Answer (score 14):

Use the following code:

```
- (IBAction)playBtnPressed {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDonePressed:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    //moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
    [moviePlayer play];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)moviePlayBackDonePressed:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [moviePlayer stop];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer];                               

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];    
    }

    [moviePlayer release];
    moviePlayer = nil;
}

- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [moviePlayer stop];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];                                              

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

- Use following line in .h file and add MediaPlayer Framework in your project

  ## import

Comment: This worked for me but you need to add this to your .h file `@property (atomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;` and then synthesise the property in your .m file `@synthesize moviePlayer;`