# audioqueue can use instead of mpmovieplayer for live audio streaming in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios6, http-live-streaming

I have read in Apple document, for live streaming of video/audio for more than 5 or 10 minute  is not allowed using `MpMoviePlayerController`. Instead you have to use `HLS`.

Is it possible to use `audioqueue` for live streaming of audio instead of `HLS (HTTP Live Streaming)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not true for live streaming of video/audio more than 5 or 10 minute is not

allowed in MpMoviePlayerController. You can try it with long video and then check if it is

working or not. but from my side it is best option for live streaming. I implement also it for

live streaming video.

Comment: then when to use HLS and when to use audioQueue?

Comment: @Vishal, Can you give me some suggestions to implement Http Live Streaming in iOS? I have studied a lots of forums and apple documents but still missing my points. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Himanshu Mahajan What are you want to play through http live streaming audio or video?

Comment: @Vishal its video. Can you provide me some code or sample examples related to it?

Comment: @Himanshu Mahajan I have play HTTP live streaming video through MPMoviePlayerViewController. Try to find implementation of MPMoviePlayerViewController & check.

Comment: @Vishal I have done the implementation of MPMoviePlayerViewController. You can check my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801942/how-ios-play-the-video-by-url/13950011#13950011   but here I am picking url and passing url in controller object. But now I want to implement Live Streaming. In my code, its not Live streaming.

Comment: Ok but you given the answer here so given answer by you is not correct/.]

Comment: Ok in my case I first of all parse streaming video through XML parse in my code then I play it through player...